# Enum.Parse From FormCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 4 CRUD form. The model has a property `MyProp` whose type is an enum:

```
public enum MyType
{
    Item1,
    Item2
}
```

In my view, I have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyProp, typeof(MyType).ToSelectList(), new { onchange="copyToHidden('MyType');" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyProp)
```

`copyToHidden()` just copies the value from the dropdown to the hidden input. `ToSelectList()` is an extension I wrote that creates a select list from the values of an enum.

I use a hidden field to save the dropdown value because I want make the dropdown readonly in some cases (disabling the dropdown). Say I choose `Item1` from the dropdown and I submit the form; there are two possibilities:

- the dropdown is disabled, and then the value is sent as `"Item1"`
- the dropdown is enabled, and then the value is sent as `"Item1,Item1"`

I then populate my model using the `FormCollection` object and using reflection. When I detect that the property type is an enum, I use `Enum.Parse` to parse the string value... and to my surprise it worked even when the dropdown is enabled: `Enum.Parse("Item1,Item1")` gives me `MyType.Item1`! Which is exactly what I want, but I'm suspicious, hence my question: **will that always work?**

Here's the c# part:

```
public enum MyType
{
    Item1,
    Item2
}

public class MyModel
{
    public MyType MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class MyModelController
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formValues)
    {
        var model = new MyModel();
        foreach (string name in formValues)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = typeof(MyModel).GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
            {
                var value = Enum.Parse(property.PropertyType, formValues[name]);// Will this always work?
                property.SetValue(model, value, null);
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't tell you if an English description of some code will always work.  YOU HAVE TO POST THE CODE YOU ARE ASKING ABOUT.  Otherwise we will just be guessing.

Comment: Why are you writing this yourself? This is what ModelBinders do... just make your function `public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)` and it'll automatically set the properties for you!

Comment: I am writing this myself because there are situations where I can't use ModelBinders, e.g. in a multi-model creation page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this behavior is due to a functionality added to Enums called [Flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx); As far as I am concerned you can have an enum value with more than one corresponded name. Take the following sample:

```
     public enum Test
     {
        A = 1,
        B = 2,
        C = 4
     } 

       var value = "A,B";
       var parsedValue = Enum.Parse(typeof (Test), value);
```

and surprisingly,

```
       parsedValue = 3
```

hence, in your situation, as far as your enum values don't conflict each others you can be sure parsing mechanism is working properly.